# Drawing a SVG with d3.js while tab is in background

Tags: javascript, scala, google-chrome, web, d3.js

**Context**: I am working on a webapp that has to display some fairly complicated and constantly updating (multiple times per second) SVG images. The updates stem from a seperate server and the SVG is updates as soon as an update is received by the web frontend. The webapp is written in [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/) and the image is created using the [d3js](https://d3js.org/) library (see also: [scala-js-d3](https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3)). We currently only support Google Chrome.

**Problem**: Once the webapp has been in a background tab for a while, the whole site gets unresponsive once navigated to again. Depending on how long the app was in the background, it sometimes takes up to 20 seconds for the application to be responsive again. Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: do you use setInterval()/setTimout() as an update mechanism or are you using requestAnimationFrame()?

Comment: No offense, but this sounds more of a desgin flaw of your application. Are you sure you need calculations/rendering while in background? Have a look at Google's announcement on handling background tabs: [*Background Tabs in Chrome 57*](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs). You may also have a look into WebWorkers or ServiceWorkers to offload work to background processing.

Comment: I am updating the SVG as soon as an update is received (which is sent by a visualization server). Neither am I using `setInterval()/setTimout()` nor `requestAnimationFrame()`, but I will look into those. Pretty sure it is a design flaw of my application, given that I am not that familiar with web developement in general. This application however will only run on industrial PCs, not connected to the internet (for now at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that works best for me is a pretty simple one:

Once the application is in a background tab or minimized (can be detected using the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)), I only update my model without drawing anything. Then, once the application is put into the foreground again, I re-draw everything. This fixed all of my performance problems.

Comment: Good idea but with transitions it might look odd once the user switches back (also possibly misleading because the transition might be between state A and D, without state B and C in-between).

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my case this behavior is something I can live with. The SVG I am drawing is awfully complicated and 'bloated', so I prefer not drawing anything at all while not visible. Upvoted your answer though, because for other cases, your solution might make more sense. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem which I worked around by not doing transitions in background tabs.

[mbostock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365814/mbostock) shows a nice snippet for doing this at https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/issues/93#issuecomment-516452828

Helper method…

```
d3.selection.prototype.maybeTransition = function(duration) {
  return duration > 0 ? this.transition().duration(duration) : this;
};
```

…to be used the following way:

```js
selection
  .maybeTransition(document.visibilityState === "visible" ? my_duration : 0)
    .attr(…
```

Capturing the page visibility events one could then even adapt the transition time in such a manner that the transition time is reduced (thus the transition sped up) in such a way that it ends in about the same time had the page not been in a background tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using setInterval() at the moment the browser might be 'punishing' you for running setInterval() in an inactive browser-tab.

You can fix this by either using requestAnimationFrame() or by monitoring the tab visibility and only using setInterval() when the tab is active.

Comment: d3.js transitions are already using `requestAnimationFrame`, see https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/src/transition/schedule.js and https://github.com/d3/d3-timer