# dc.js charts tab freezes in Chrome browser when switched back from other active tab after a while

Tags: performance, google-chrome, d3.js, tabs, dc.js

I have about 10 bar charts in a page with real time data ticking and all charts are being updated based those ticks and it works beautifully.
However, if I have multiple tabs open in Chrome and after a while looking at other sites when I come back to dc.js charts tab it freezes, memory size is rapidly going up, and it takes really long time to come back to normal.
I found that other people reported similar issue using d3.js and mbostock recommended not to use setInterval and use d3.interval instead, https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/issues/34 or use page visibility API, [Drawing a SVG with d3.js while tab is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042400/drawing-a-svg-with-d3-js-while-tab-is-in-background).
But I guess these things are internal to dc.js since it interacts with d3 directly to render updates.

Here's how I define a chart.

```
export const chartFunc = (divRef, ndx, color) => {
  const dimension = ndx.dimension(d => d.category);
  const group = dimension.group().reduceSum(d => d.amount);

  const chart = dc.rowChart(divRef);
  chart
    .height(310).width(300)
    .dimension(dimension)
    .group(group)
    .data(g => g.top(15))
    .colors(color)
    .elasticX(true)
    .x(scaleBand())
  return chart;
};
```

And data ticks are pushed via websocket, saga, redux, data property of the component, and then the updated crossfilter context to child components.
After the update happened to crossfilter, I call "redrawAll()" to refresh charts.

```
  const [ndx, updateNDX] = useState(null);
  const [hasNDX, updateHasNDX] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(initialLoad && !hasNDX) {
      updateNDX(crossfilter(data));
      updateHasNDX(true);
    } else {
      data.forEach(update => {
        ndx.remove(d => d._id === update._id);
        ndx.add([update]);
      });

      dc.redrawAll();
    }
  }, [data]);
```

Anyone experienced similar issue or any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: I think I have seen this. You should probably pause your updates and buffer any changes until the tab is active again. I don't have an example on hand, sorry. I could work one up later in the week if you're still stuck.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your thoughtful reply. Can I let ticks flow into crossfilter but don't call redrawAll() hoping it will avoid queuing up the transitions while any calculation is still being done and ready for redraw all updates at once when the page is visible?

Comment: Yes I think that should work - data is pulled at the beginning of redraw, so the changes will be accumulated.